# How can I get the value of a dropdown menu outside a form submission with GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have two dropdowns in my site, one for chosing a region and one for chosing a city. Both dropdowns are not within a form. I want to be able to capture the user's selection of both drodowns' values with GTM and show the results in GA.

All the material I've found online all explain how to do so in a submission form and won't work in my case. ¿Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-selection-drop-list/

Comment: I've tried that and it won't work either. I was hoping someone had a different solution.

Comment: Silly but geniune q, in what way was it not working for you? If you use the custom event mentioned in the article to trigger a GA event, you could then pass the selected values in the dataLayer with the GA event as custom dimensions.

Comment: I followed step by step, but I guess I'm probably missing something. I'm not a JS expert and I believe that's not helping me either. I was wondering if there was another way of doing this. I was able to track a form I have (that has a dropdown menu), and I did this without JS, just using Data Layer and it worked.

Comment: are you able to share a link to the page with the drop downs on it? If i can take a look at hte code, then can make a few suggestions